# xmlworker is missing in iText 7 core

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am trying to use iText 7 in Java. Want to covert HTML/XHTML to PDF.

Apparently `xmlworker.jar` doesn't exist in `iText 7 core`.

What is the replacement for iText 7?

Any solutions?

Comment: As for now, XmlWorker is not available for iText7

Comment: Thank your for reply. I am evaluating features of iText 7. I hear that support and updates seems no longer available for iText 5 after 2017, what is the schedule for the release of xmlworker in iText 7? Whether the feature is no longer available after iText 7 or not?

Answer (score 5):

XML Worker is the next thing on the road map at iText, so yes, it will be available for iText 7. But first we need to finish the port of iText 7 for Java to iText 7 for C# and we're still working hard on documenting iText 7. See for instance: [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks).

In open source, one releases often, one releases soon. Rather than keeping *all* code closed until *everything* is finished, we opted for the open source way of releasing: whatever is ready, gets released. Whatever isn't ready, will be released as soon as it's ready.

The major overhaul of iText requires us to rewrite XML Worker. The benefit: iText 7 was written with XML Worker in mind. All the items marked with a key in the tutorial I mentioned are "new in iText 7", e.g. inheritance of properties (which allows us to apply CSS in a much better way).

You'll see significant improvements when it's done.

Comment: @Bruno Is this answer still valid. I see a html2pdf on the site.

Comment: @HopeKing Yes, we have released [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) and yes, it's a tad confusing that the package names / Maven id is `html2pdf` (html2pdf = pdfHTML). You can find a tutorial here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml

Comment: @Bruno Thanks. Looks like this is not available on maven and needs a license key rightway. Is there a way to test how it works ?

Comment: @Bruno I use maven as my build tool. Hence i was using <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId> from https://itextpdf.com/blog/itext-702-release but I get a error "Missing artifact com.itextpdf:html2pdf:jar:1.0.1". Is there a maven dependency in your link ? Sorry, if I missed something obvious

Comment: @BrunoLowagie can you help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

iText `pdfHTML` module has been released as a replacement for `XmlWorker`.
C# version can be downloaded from the [NuGet Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/). Java version can be downloaded from the [Artifactory](https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/simple/General/releases/com/itextpdf/html2pdf).

The main class you are looking for is `HtmlConverter`. It has a lot of static method overloads for converting `html` either to a list of elements to be future added to layout structures, to a whole `com.itextpdf.layout.Document` instance, or right to the `.pdf` file.

Example of converting `.html` file to `.pdf`:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(htmlFilePath), new File(outPdfFilePath));
```

Example of converting html to layout elements:

```
String html = "<p>Hello world!</p>";
List<IElement> lst = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(html);
```

Also, `pdfHTML` now supports `@media` rules, so you might want to provide a configuration which will be used for applying CSS, for instance to use `@media print` instructions, you would need to set up `MediaDeviceDescription` accordingly:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties()
     .setMediaDeviceDescription(new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.PRINT));
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(htmlPath), new File(outPdfPath), properties);
```

To specify the set of fonts you would like to use when converting HTML to PDF, you can also set up a `FontProvider`:

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
fontProvider.addDirectory(fontsDir)
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
```

Or you can use the `DefaultFontProvider` and specify its settings in the constructor:

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, true);
properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
```

`DefaultFontProvider` has three parameters in the constructor: first one is to specify whether to use Standard fonts (`Helvetica`, `Courier`, `Times` etc), second one to specify whether to use fonts that are shipped with `pdfHTML`, and the third one to specify whether to load system fonts. `DefaultFontProvider` is just a subclass of `FontProvider` and therefore you can always call `addDirectory` or `addFont` after the instance has been created.